# error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property x does not exist ... on Deno compile

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, deno, oak

This is my first time using Oak and Deno. I learn it from https://www.robinwieruch.de/deno-oak-rest-api and documentation. I want to use REST-API deno using this script (server.ts).

```
import { v4 } from 'https://deno.land/std/uuid/mod.ts';

import {
  Application,
  Router,
  helpers,
} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';

interface User {
  id: string;
  username: string;
}

const users = new Map<string, User>();

users.set('1', {
  id: '1',
  username: 'Robin Wieruch',
});

users.set('2', {
  id: '2',
  username: 'Dave Davids',
});

interface Message {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  userId: string;
}

const messages = new Map<string, Message>();

messages.set('1', {
  id: '1',
  text: 'Hello World',
  userId: '1',
});

messages.set('2', {
  id: '2',
  text: 'By World',
  userId: '2',
});

const port = 8000;
const app = new Application();

const router = new Router();

router.get('/session', (ctx) => {
  ctx.response.body = users.get(ctx.state.me.id);
});

router.get('/users', (ctx) => {
  ctx.response.body = Array.from(users.values());
});

router.get('/users/:userId', (ctx) => {
  const { userId } = helpers.getQuery(ctx, { mergeParams: true });
  ctx.response.body = users.get(userId);
});

router.get('/messages', (ctx) => {
  ctx.response.body = Array.from(messages.values());
});

router.get('/messages/:messageId', (ctx) => {
  const { messageId } = helpers.getQuery(ctx, { mergeParams: true });
  ctx.response.body = messages.get(messageId);
});

router.post('/messages', async (ctx) => {
  const id = v4.generate();

  const {
    value: { text },
  } = await ctx.request.body();

  messages.set(id, {
    id,
    text,
    userId: ctx.state.me.id,
  });

  ctx.response.body = messages.get(id);
});

router.delete('/messages/:messageId', async (ctx) => {
  const { messageId } = helpers.getQuery(ctx, { mergeParams: true });

  const isDeleted = messages.delete(messageId);

  ctx.response.body = isDeleted;
});

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.state = { me: users.get('1') };

  await next();
});

app.use(router.allowedMethods());
app.use(router.routes());

app.addEventListener('listen', () => {
  console.log(`Listening on: localhost:${port}`);
});

await app.listen({ port });
```

After running it with `deno run --allow-net --allow-read server.ts` I get the following error:

```
$ deno run --allow-net --allow-read server.ts 
Check file:///home/astrid/git/javascript/deno/deno-oak-rest-api/server.ts
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Promise<any> | Promise<URLSearchParams> | FormDataReader | Promise<string> | Promise<Uint8Array> | undefined'.
    value: { text },
             ~~~~
    at file:///home/astrid/git/javascript/deno/deno-oak-rest-api/server.ts:77:14
```

This are my version

```
$ deno --version
deno 1.3.3
v8 8.6.334
typescript 4.0.2
```

How to solve this error ?

Comment: Just heads up: If you would like to check this repo for deno rest api boilerplate:
https://github.com/vicky-gonsalves/deno_rest

Answer (score 2):

> Was changed around #201
>
> - `ctx.request.body()` is no longer async so you can drop `await`
> - Now accepts argument for type of body
> - `value` is now a promise so needs to be awaited (which is what the ts issue highlights)
>
> Not sure what body type you were using before but here are some usages in the latest version
>
> ```
> // for JSON:
> const { value } = ctx.request.body({ type: "json" });
> const { text } = await value;
>
> // for FormData:
> const { value } = ctx.request.body({ type: "form-data" });
> const formData = await value.read();
> const { text } = formData.fields;
> ```

See https://github.com/oakserver/oak/issues/239

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : we can access parse data from request for JSON as

```
const result = ctx.request.body({ type: "json" });
const data = await result.value;
```